# Regexp_like check for symbol in string

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

If I want to check that string contains `@`symbol I can write something like

```
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'@')
```

or

```
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column, '.*@.*')
```

What is the difference between these two forms? 
And why `REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'@')` returns true even if string has other symbols than `@`? For example it matches with `mail@mail.com` and `12@`

Naturally `'@'` looks like **exact** string match for me, and `'.*@.*'` I read as 'any string with that symbol'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three all function identically and will return true if any number of characters precede or follow the `@` symbol:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'@')
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'.*@.*')
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'^.*@.*$', 'n')
```

*(You need the `'n'` match parameter for the last example if you have multi-line data otherwise the `.` wildcard character will not match newlines and the match will fail.)*

If you want an exact match then look for the start-of-string (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) immediately preceding and following the symbol:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(source_column,'^@$')
```